# How to Set 2 Host Names for a single computer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to set two different host names for a single computer in Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Is this for name resolution to the Windows 7 machine from a local LAN?  If so you can add  a manual entry to the local dns server.  This may not work if this is a lap top and is on multiple LANs.

Or if you are just looking for this host name to work from the machine itself you can add an entry to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Comment: This is for the local LAN.